# Python kivymd ids -> Problem accessing ids in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a notes application and I'm trying to access the `MDList` class through the id I provided in the notes_container. I'm working in a Home screen and whenever I try to import notes_container by writing self.root.ids.notes_container, I get an error. I've been having this problem in some of my earlier projects and any help on this will be appreciated. Below is my code: What might I be doing wrong.

Main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.toast import toast
import mysql.connector
import datetime
from kivymd.uix.list import TwoLineAvatarListItem

Window.size = (350, 600)
DATABASE = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        database = "notes"
)
cursor = DATABASE.cursor()

class ScreensManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Home(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM notes_table")
        self.fetched = cursor.fetchall()

        for i in range(len(self.fetched)):
            self.root.ids.notes_container.add_widget(TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = f"{self.fetched[i][0]}", secondary_text = f"{self.fetched[i][1]}"))
            print(self.fetched[i][0])

        DATABASE.commit()

        return super().on_enter(*args)

class Create(Screen):
    title_field = ObjectProperty(None)
    content_field = ObjectProperty(None)
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    def erase_action(self):
        self.title_field.text = ""
        self.content_field.text = ""

    def save_action(self):
        if self.title_field.text == "" or self.content_field.text == "":
            toast("Nothing to save.")
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO notes_table (Title, Content, Date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (self.title_field.text, self.content_field.text, self.current_date))

            self.title_field.text = ""
            self.content_field.text = ""
            toast("Note saved.")
            
            DATABASE.commit()

class Edit(Screen):
    pass

class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.title = ("Notes App")
        return Builder.load_file("styles.kv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().run()
```

Styles.kv

```
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#: set theme_color get_color_from_hex("#6a0dad")

ScreensManager:
    Home:
    Create:
    Edit:

<MainLayout@MDBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1

<NavbarBtn@MDFloatingActionButton>:
    elevation: 0
    md_bg_color: theme_color
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

<Home>:
    name: "home"
    notes_container: notes_container

    MainLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            md_bg_color: theme_color
            title: "Notes App"
            left_action_items: [["pen"]]

            NavbarBtn:
                icon: "plus"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "create"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            padding: 20

            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: notes_container


<Create>:
    name: "create"
    title_field: title_field
    content_field: content_field

    MainLayout:
        MDToolbar:
            md_bg_color: theme_color
            title: "Notes App"
            left_action_items: [["pen"]]

            NavbarBtn:
                icon: "delete"
                on_press:
                    root.erase_action()
        
            NavbarBtn:
                icon: "check"
                on_press:
                    root.save_action()
        
        MainLayout:
            padding: 20
            spacing: '10dp'

            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                adaptive_height: True

                MDTextField:
                    hint_text: "Note title..."
                    line_color_focus: theme_color
                    id: title_field
                
                MDTextField:
                    hint_text: "Note content..."
                    line_color_focus: theme_color
                    multiline: True
                    id: content_field

            MDBoxLayout:
                MDBoxLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    adaptive_width: True

                    NavbarBtn:
                        icon: "arrow-left"
                        on_release:
                            root.manager.current = "home"
                            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<Edit>:
    name: "edit"

    MDLabel:
        text: "Label"
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\coding\python\MD Projects\Yt-Md-projects\Notes app\main.py", line 67, in <module>
     Main().run()
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "d:\coding\python\MD Projects\Yt-Md-projects\Notes app\main.py", line 64, in build
     return Builder.load_file("styles.kv")
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 305, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 407, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     widget.add_widget(child)
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1001, in add_widget
     self.current = widget.name
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 520, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 567, in kivy.properties.Property.set
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 606, in kivy.properties.Property._dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1213, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Ian GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1069, in on_current
     screen.dispatch('on_enter')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "d:\coding\python\MD Projects\Yt-Md-projects\Notes app\main.py", line 30, in on_enter
     self.root.ids.notes_container.add_widget(TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = f"{self.fetched[i][0]}", secondary_text = f"{self.fetched[i][1]}"))
 AttributeError: 'Home' object has no attribute 'root'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what is wrong. The `Home` object does not have a `root` attribute. If you are trying to access the `ids` of the `Home` object, just use `self.ids`:

```
        self.ids.notes_container.add_widget(TwoLineAvatarListItem(text = f"{self.fetched[i][0]}", secondary_text = f"{self.fetched[i][1]}"))
```

Comment: That too doesn't work. It is giving another error.

Comment: What is the new error?